# How to cut from the 1st character to -7 character in awk?

Tags: awk

I have a file with multiple lines.

Which the second column is the `user_id`, but the last seven number are random numbers.

It need to be trimmed off to get the authentic ID.

So what I need is to get the `1st character to the -7 character` of the second column of each line.

I've searched `substr` function of awk, it seems can't handle this job directly.

So, how to cut from the 1st character to -7 character in awk?

Comment: what about : `susbtr(X,1,length(X)-7)` ?

Comment: `awk '{$2=substr($2,1, length($2)-7); print $2}' file`

Comment: @jasonwryan,@Archemar that was genius, I didn't consider I can use length func here. Too obstinate in finding some thing similar like `[:-7]` in python.

Comment: Why was the question voted down?

Comment: @Archemar, so I guess `awk -v id=$TARGET_ID 'substr($2, 1, length($2) -7) == id'` will print out every line of the file that its `ID` is equal to `TARGET_ID`?

Comment: Yes it should print the whole line.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{ print substr($2,1,length($2)-7) }'
```

If length($2) <= 7, you'll get no output. Should there be a minimum length? If so, you can define a min() function in awk:

```
awk 'function min(a,b){return a<b?b:a}  ..<rest of code>..'
```

Comment: Shouldn't your function be in a BEGIN rule?

Comment: @Medievalist Not at all. if you try to define a function within a BEGIN block, you'll get an error.

Comment: you are right, I just tested!  
  
Functions need to be outside curly braces, apparently.  Slightly hilariously, Arnold Robbins quotes Brian Kernighan as saying "The notation for function locals is appalling (all my fault too, which makes it worse)."  
  
BTW, your function returns max, not min.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the operations need to be done on the second column (trim last 7 chars):

`[whatever command you use to open your file] | awk '{ print $2 }' | rev | cut -c 8- | rev`

Here's the breakdown:

`awk '{ print $2 }'` Gets the second column of the file

`rev` prepares the string (reverses it). I don't think `cut` can remove last N characters, so this thing removes first N chars from the reversed string.

`cut -c 8-` Removes the first 7 characters from the string. (found out by trial and error, needs verification)

`rev` reverses the processed string. This displays the original string, but without the 7 character thing.

Comment: OP asked how to do it in Awk (the presumption being without external tools like `rev` and `cut`), and the comments clearly indicate this is possible...